# CollectionView - Binding Data doesn't work

Tags: maui

I'm exercising on my first MAUI application, however, I have problem to view the data. With debugging I can see the list is not empty, there is data, as well I'm passing the list data to ItemSource.
What could be the issue?

[image: Screenshot]

My code on `onAppearing()`:

```cs
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ApiService service = new ApiService();
        var newsResult = await service.GetNews();

        foreach(var item in newsResult.Articles)
        {
            ArticleList.Add(item);
        }

        CvNews.ItemsSource= ArticleList;

    }
```

xaml:

```xml
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="CvNews">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="15"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                        <Image HeightRequest="200" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

In the image source I add default image from the resources, and the image is displayed

Article:

```
public class Article
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title;

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description;

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public string Content;

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url;

        [JsonProperty("image")]
        public string Image;

        [JsonProperty("publishedAt")]
        public DateTime PublishedAt;

        [JsonProperty("source")]
        public Source Source;
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("totalArticles")]
        public int TotalArticles;

        [JsonProperty("articles")]
        public List<Article> Articles;
    }

    public class Source
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name;

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string Url;
    }
```

Comment: please post the code for `Article`

Comment: you can only bind to public properties.  None of the items in `Article` are [C# properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: Move the code in the OnAppearing() method to the Code Behind and then check.

Comment: You can also refer the official doc: [Populate a CollectionView with data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only bind to **public properties**

```
<Image HeightRequest="200" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
<Label FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
```

neither `Image` nor `Title` are **public properties**

```
public string Title;
```

to make it a property

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```